# Migrate to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL using Database Migration Service

Tags: database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I would like to migrate a **specific database** from my Cloud SQL (Postgresql) instance to another Cloud SQL instance using GCP Database Migration Service.

According to GCP documentation:

```
Database Migration Service migrates ALL databases under the 
source instance other than the following databases:

For Cloud SQL sources: template databases template0 and template1
```

How can I migrate only **one specific database** from the Cloud SQL Instance?

Comment: marian.vladoi, do let me know if the information below was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Database Migration Service could be used to move one Cloud SQL instance from one to another.
As per your requirement that I understood from above question details , you can specify specific parameters as below to select a specific database from the available ones:

- Open the Source database engine drop-down list and select the
  classification type of your source database
- In the Connection profile name field, enter a name for the connection
  profile for your source database, such as My Connection Profile.
- Keep the auto-generated Connection profile ID.
- Enter Connectivity information: If you're replicating from a
  self-hosted database, then enter the Hostname or IP address (domain
  or IP) and Port to access the host. (The default PostgreSQL port is
  5432.)

Database Migration Service uses this information in the connection profile to migrate data from your specific source database to the destination Cloud SQL database instance.
This is a well documented procedure, of which you can find information in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/quickstart)